# Using an R function to hash values produces a repeating value across rows

Tags: r, powerbi, powerquery

I'm using the following query:

```
let
    Source = {1..5},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Numbers"}, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Letters", each Character.FromNumber([Numbers] + 64)),
    #"Run R script" = R.Execute("# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script#(lf)#(lf)library(""digest"")#(lf)#(lf)dataset$SuffixedLetters <- paste(dataset$Letters, ""_suffix"")#(lf)dataset$HashedLetters <- digest(dataset$Letters, ""md5"", serialize = TRUE)#(lf)output<-dataset",[dataset=#"Added Custom"]),
    output = #"Run R script"{[Name="output"]}[Value]
in
    output
```

which leads to the resulting table:

[image]

And the here is the R script with better formatting:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

library("digest")

dataset$SuffixedLetters <- paste(dataset$Letters, "_suffix")
dataset$HashedLetters <- digest(dataset$Letters, "md5", serialize = TRUE)
output<-dataset
```

The 'paste' function appears to iterate over rows and resolve on each row with the new input.  But the 'digest' function only appears to return the first value in the table across all rows.

I don't know why the behavior of the two functions would seem to operate differently.  Can anyone advise how to get the 'HashedLetters' column to resolve using the values from each row instead of just the initial one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```r
dataset$HashedLetters <- sapply(dataset$Letters, digest, algo = "md5", serialize = TRUE)
```

`digest` works on a whole object at a time, not individual elements of a vector.

```r
vec <- letters[1:3]
digest::digest(vec, algo="md5", serialize=TRUE)
# [1] "38ce1fe9e19a222505e693e8bdd8aeec"
sapply(vec, digest::digest, algo="md5", serialize=TRUE)
#                                  a                                  b                                  c 
# "127a2ec00989b9f7faf671ed470be7f8" "ddf100612805359cd81fdc5ce3b9fbba" "6e7a8c1c098e8817e3df3fd1b21149d1"
```